# How to set up jQuery hide(), adding Class and remove Class to run properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

My HTML Code is like this :

```
    ...
    @foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)    
        ...
        <div class="iteration">
             <input type='hidden' value='<?php  echo $value['HCode'].'#'.$value['HName'].'#'.$value['CheckIn'].'#'.$value['CheckOut']   ?>' id='tes'>
           ...

           {{ $value['HotelNo'] }}      
           {{ $value['HotelName'] }}
           ...     
           <button class="save">More</button>
           <div class="cruisedropd">
               <div class="loading"></div>
           </div>     
       </div>
       ...
    @endforeach
    ...
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
   $(function(){
        $('.save').click(function () {
            var $parent = $(this).closest('div.iteration');
            if ($parent.hasClass("is_loading")) {
                $(".cruisedropd").hide();
                $parent.removeClass("is_loading")
            } 
            else {
                $parent.addClass("is_loading")
                var bla = $parent.find('.tes:first').val();
                console.log(bla);
                ...

                $parent.find('.loading').html('<img src="http://preloaderss.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "hotel-detail",
                    ...
                    success: function (response) {
                        ...
                        var elem = $parent.find('.loading').empty();  //remove org content
                        for(var i=0; i<response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel.length; i++){  //make sure to use var
                            elem.append("<p>" + response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo + "</p>");  //add the new content
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            } 
        });
    });
```

When the first time I click more in the first line, there is the process of loading and displaying detailed information. After that, I click more again, and it hides the detail information. Then I click more again no action. It looks like jQuery hide(), adding Class and  remove Class not run properly

Why did it happen?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: _My HTML Code_, that not an HTML code in your OP.

Comment: Your $parent.removeClass(); and $parent.addClass(); statements should end in semicolons(;) which must be leading to a syntax error when you try running your code.

Comment: @stark semi colons aren't necessary in javascript

Comment: @stark Not necessarily. Semicolons can be omitted in a number of cases; this shouldn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it, in what cases can semicolons be omitted then ? @TimLewis

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that your hidden input has an ID on it and it's inside of a loop, therefore creating duplicate IDs on the HTML page. This may not be the source of your issues, but it certainly isn't helping you. Also, your bla variable doesn't return anything because you have a class selector, and no html element that you have provided has the class of "tes". There is only the id of "tes", as I mentioned, that gets duplicated.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, It's an HTML code. It's Laravel View

Comment: @mhodges, I understand your statement. But I still difficult to implement into my case

Comment: @mosestoh Please post the actual HTML generated by lavarel which is displayed in browser. Secondly try creating an [mcve]. You have posted `...` in many places so I assume there are other code. Issue might be lying there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that once you hide div with class `cruisedropd` you never show it again:

1. First time you click `more` and check `if ($parent.hasClass("is_loading")) {` nothing is loading yet, so you append loading gif and start ajax
2. Second time you click `more` and check `if ($parent.hasClass("is_loading")) {` you find `$parent` having `is_loading` class and, besides removing this class you also hide div with class `cruisedropd` which contains div with class `loading` with the loading gif.
3. Next time wheh you click `more` even if the div with class `loading` is supposed to show a loading gif, it doesn't because its parent `cruisedropd` is still hidden.

Show your div with class `cruisedropd` after doing `$parent.find('.loading').html('<img src=...')`:

`$(".cruisedropd").show();`